# php set PHP Session using tablename.column

Tags: php

i am running this SQL Query in PHP:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM customer
        JOIN contacts ON (contacts.company_sequence = customer.sequence)
        WHERE customer.resellerid = '".$_POST["rid"]."' 
        AND contacts.email = '".$email."' 
        AND contacts.password = '".md5($password)."' ";
        $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        $result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
```

and then trying to set a session variable:

```
$_SESSION["sequence"]=$result["contacts.sequence"];
```

for the sequence column in the contacts table but its not setting it.

sessions are working fine, am i setting it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$_SESSION["sequence"]=$result["sequence"];
```

you get an associative array witought the table name

Comment: but surely it doesnt know what table to get the sequence column from?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, `SELECT *` just means "grab whatever columns there are from the rest of the query". It does not prefix their names with any label for which table they came from, and does not have any mechanism for distinguishing columns from different tables with the same name.

If you want to be sure of what columns come back from a query, you should always list them specifically in your `SELECT` statement, e.g. `SELECT contacts.sequence FROM ...`; note that `contacts.` here is not part of the column name, but a label used *within the query* to distinguish which column you're referring to. The key in your results array will just be `'sequence'`.

You can also use `AS` to give the column a different name in the result than in the actual table, so `SELECT contacts.sequence as contacts_sequence FROM ...` will select the same column, but give it a key of `'contacts_sequence'` in the result.

As pointed out in a comment, the columns retrieved can easily be verified by adding `print_r($result)` or similar in your code.